# Sklearn Error:R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I built a data.csv in order to see how this works. So I did this one.

```
s1;s2;s3;s4;result
1;2;3;4;5;15
2;1;3;1;2;9
19;21;0;0;0;40
11;9;0;1;5;26
5;5;5;5;5;25
80;1;1;1;1;84
1;2;3;1;1;8
1;0;0;1;1;3
10;10;10;10;20;60
```

As you can see, `result` is the sum of `s1,s2,s3 and s4.` So I did this.

```
data = pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep=';', index_col=0)
data = data[['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 'result']]
predict = 'result'


x = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array(data[predict])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)

linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear.fit(x_train, y_train)

acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)
print(acc)
```

But I got this error.

> C:\Users\Sharki\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\regression.py:543: UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples.
>     warnings.warn(msg, UndefinedMetricWarning)

What's happening?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726381/r2-score-is-not-well-defined-with-less-than-two-samples-python-sklearn], looks like your question has been asked before.

Comment: I saw that post before posting this one, but I think isn't the same case. (and if so, then I'm so bad understanding it).

Comment: I ran the same script on my terminal but it renders `acc=0`. Maybe you want to check the inconsistency? A side talk, there is something off with your data structure: say on row one you have 5 values, `1;2;3;4;5;` but only 4 columns `s1;s2;s3;s4;`.  You need to have one more column, otherwise the first number becomes automatically index by your `read_csv`.

Comment: @tianlinhe all these issues have already been addressed in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have asked for too low a `test_size` in your `train_test_split`; `test_size=0.1`, in your dataset of only 10 rows, corresponds to a single data point in your test set:

```
x_test, y_test
# (array([[2, 3, 4, 5]]), array([15]))
```

hence the error (actually a warning, since `nan` was returned).

Change it to at least 0.2:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
[...]
print(acc)
# -88.65298209559413

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
[...]
print(acc)
# -0.5210446297916358
```

and prepare for **wild** fluctuations in your resulting R^2 (as already shown in the examples above), due to the extremely small size of your data.

**Additionally**, notice that you actually have 6 fields in your CSV file but only 5 column names, the result being pandas interpreting the first column as index when reading the dataframe (notice that `1` is missing from the `x_test` variable shown above). You should add an `s5` in the header and remove `index_col=0`, i.e.:

```
data = pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep=';')
```

Visually inspecting your variables, especially in case of errors, always pays off.

Irrelevant to your question, but to term the R^2 as `acc` (implying accuracy) is not good practice, since R2 & accuracy are different performance measures, and accuracy is meaningless in regression problems (it's only meaningful in classification).

Comment: So s1 is treated like an index? Is there any way to use s1 as an attribute instead of an index? I'm so sorry because I'm so lost with all this. And thanks a lot for your help! I know it's kinda offtopic, but I would be very grateful if you could tell me where or how to improve these skills.

Comment: @GeorgiaFernández you just need to change the header of your file to `s1;s2;s3;s4;s5;result`, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Sorry for bother you once again, I changed my file to `s1;s2;s3;s4;s5;result`, so I assumed that I needed to change my code as well to `data = data[[ 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 'result']]` but it returns a neagtive integer, why?

Comment: @GeorgiaFernández no, it should be `data = data[[ 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 'result']]`; I said add `s5`, not removing `s1`. But in any case, this line is redundant (your `data` variable is already like that).

Comment: then it returns `KeyError: "['s1'] not in index"` But ignoring the line as you said it seems it works, what's wrong with that line?

Comment: @GeorgiaFernández issue is with `index_col=0` - you should remove it. Updated answer (missed it because I was trying to solve the issue you asked for, not everything else...).

Comment: I see, sorry for everything, I'm new in this, and well... Sorry and thanks! :)